# PHP adding $ signs into strings without it being a variable?

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I'm making a setup page where people can write their database login etc and that will then create a config.php file on their webserver with the info but obviously I can't just write

```
$file = fopen("config.php", "w");
fwrite($file, "$dbName = $dbName");
```

I actually tried

```
$file = fopen("config.php", "w");
fwrite($file, "$" . "dbName = $dbName");
```

But that doesn't work either.

Any way to store it as a PHP variable in a file I write using PHP?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: `fwrite($file, '$dbName' . " = $dbName");`

Comment: For reference, see [PHP:Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and [...difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Either escape the dollar sign or use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As PHP Document says

> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret the
>   following escape sequences for special characters: \$ Dollar Sign

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

So if you want to use `$` in a double-quotes strings use `\$` instead of `$`.

Or simply use single quotes